# Access invalid member names in JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I have this string

```
"{\"0\":\"test\"}"
```

I'm using [JSON.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). I tried the line

```
var j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input_string)
var t = j["0"]; //This causes a compile error
var k = j.Keys
```

I could perhaps change my input string but I rather keep it this way. How do I access it in json.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you're using the non-generic `DeserializeObject` which returns an `object`, hence the compile time error. One possibility is to parse the json to a `JObject`:

```
void Main()
{
    var json = "{\"0\":\"test\"}";
    var jobject = JObject.Parse(json);
    Console.WriteLine(jobject["0"]);
}
```

The other is to create a class and annotate it with the proper `JsonProperty` attribute:

```
void Main()
{
    var json = "{\"0\":\"test\"}";
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<X>(json);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Foo);
}

public class X
{
    [JsonProperty("0")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**

You can iterate that `JObject` using `foreach`:

```
foreach (var element in jobject)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {element.Key}, Value: {element.Value }");
}
```

Or using LINQ:

```
var enumerable = jobject.AsJEnumerable()
                        .Cast<JProperty>()
                        .Select(x => new { Key = x.Name, Value = x.Value });
```

Comment: What if I don't know the key? I see `j.Count` works but `j[0]` throws an exception. I can't seem to figure out how to get each key

Comment: Your question is basically *"How do I get all keys from a `JObject`"*?

Comment: @acidzombie24 See my edit. Iterating the `JObject` will give you key value pairs which you can use.

Comment: That works. I MUCH rather use linq here but this is fine. I figured it out. Pretty trivial. Just use `IDictionary<string, JToken>` instead of var

Comment: @acidzombie24 See my edit again :) You can use LINQ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to @Yuval's answer is to use [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx):

```
dynamic j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input_string);
string t = j["0"];
Console.WriteLine(t); //Prints out "test"
```

---

If you want to iterate over all key / values:

```
foreach(JProperty prop in j) {
    Console.WriteLine(prop.Name); // Prints out "0";
    Console.WriteLine(prop.Value); // Prints out "test"
}
```

---

## If you can't use dynamic

Then you may use the `JObject` returned to you by the JSON deserializer:

```
JObject j = (JObject) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input_string);
string t = j.GetValue("0").Value<string>();
Console.WriteLine(t); // Prints out "test"
```

And it can be iterated like:

```
foreach(var prop in j) {
    Console.WriteLine(prop.Key); // Prints out "0"
    Console.WriteLine(prop.Value.Value<string>()); // Prints out "test"
}
```